# Replace PHP's float datatype

Tags: php, floating-point

Imagine a codebase that is filled with bugs due to floating point inaccuracies. We are going by the assumption that refactoring or rewriting the code is not an option.

Of course, PHP offers [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) and/or [BC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) for higher precision. However, implementing them will prove an impossible task considering the restrictions above.

Is there a way (perhaps through a PHP module or a core patch) to completely replace the PHP float type to something more precise? There will of course be a performance penalty, but this is taken into consideration.

Does it exist? If it doesn't, how bad of an idea is it for me to write one? ;)

Comment: It's not limited to PHP. How do you expect to accurately  represent `1/3` as a float?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: That's the thing... the program can call it a float all day long, I want the computer (PHP in this case) to abstract it into anything that offers more precision.

Comment: All I can say is best of luck.

Comment: You're never supposed to do `if( $float1 == $float2 )` in any language, it should be `if( abs($float1-$float2) < $tolerance )`. Also, the precision of floats in PHP is [platform-dependant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

Comment: @WesleyMurch: that sounds rather sarcastic ;) care to explain why?

Comment: PHP isn't like .NET or Ruby or Python. Types are not classes, and as such, they can't simply be extended. You would have to probably checkout PHP's source and compile a custom version. Chances are it'd probably be easier to clean up the codebase

Comment: @Sammitch: I know how floats work, that's not what the question is about.

Comment: @DanielSloof It was a bit sarcastic but I truly meant it and wish you luck. Your question "*how bad of an idea is it for me to write one?*" is a bit hairy. Also *"refactoring or rewriting the code is not an option"* seems a bit dense given that your willing to write something new to handle this yourself.

Comment: @DanielSloof - if you've ever peered into the abyss that is the PHP codebase, you'd immediately feel the same way :P

Comment: @slugonamission: Fair enough ;)

Comment: Could we see some code that you are having trouble with, that might give some ideas.  The more examples the better

Comment: @Sammitch: First, the question does not indicate any problems regarding `==`. Rounding errors affect **all** functions, not just the `==` function, so there is no reason to single `==` out for special treatment. Second, that common advice to change make tests for equality permissive is bad advice, since it increases false positives and is often given as advice when the giver has no knowledge about how harmful false positives would be in the application, and because the advice is of little use without some method of determining the proper tolerance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might actually consider using [SPL Types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php) which provide an OO wrapper around the scalar PHP datatypes. You could then extend SplFloat to replace the internal representation with whatever you wanted.

Of course, you'd still have to modify every float assignment in your code to use SplFloat instead of the native scalar float

Comment: Interesting... so I could essentially do operator overloading with this and implement those operations with BC Math. It would still require changes to the codebase, but sed could save me a lot of trouble there... I'm marking this accepted for now.

Comment: In case you're interested in the slightest, I will try my luck with a custom class and operator overloading of http://pecl.php.net/package/operator

Comment: It's not something I'd do myself, but I'd be interested to know how it works out if you want to post a follow-up here at some point